# Почему не работает CSS3 анимация в firefox и opera!?

Tags: css3, анимация, css

Не работает анимация в firefox и opera, хотя прописаны вендорные префиксы!! хелп
ЗЫ версии браузеров последние, в chrome и safari работает

```
.box{
    -webkit-animation: loop 25s linear 0s infinite normal;
    -moz-animation: loop 25s linear 0s infinite normal;
    -o-animation: loop 25s linear 0s infinite normal;
    animation: loop 25s linear 0s infinite normal;
}
@keyframes 'loop' {
    from {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to {transform: rotate(360deg);}   
}
@-webkit-keyframes 'loop' {
    from {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to {-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg);}   
}
@-moz-keyframes 'loop' {
    from {-moz-transform: rotate(0deg); transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to {-moz-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg);}   
}
@-o-keyframes 'loop' {
    from {-o-transform: rotate(0deg); transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to {-o-transform: rotate(360deg); transform: rotate(360deg);}   
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте loop писать без кавычек. В [спеках](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/#keyframes) без кавычек стоит.

Comment: Реально помогло!!! Спасибо огромное
самое прикольное я убирал кавычке, но в этот момент у меня везде стояли префиксы -webkit-, когда заменил префиксы не догадался опять попробовать с кавычками... ^_^

Comment: @unlike777, если Вам дали верный ответ, отметьте его как правильный (нажмите на галочку :)).